# Trying to find a pattern given multiple FFT data sets using Amplitude, Frequency, and Phase

Tags: mathematical-statistics, matlab, pattern-recognition, signal-processing

I have about 90+ audio files that I have the FFT data in frequency, amplitude, and phase. I'm trying to find patterns that are found throughout the 90+ audio files but I'm at a loss.  **I can create individual plots all day but I'm not sure how to look for patterns found throughout 90+ audio files**, does anyone have any ideas how to find patterns given 90+ audio files given the FFT data in frequency, amplitude, and phase.   Here are some of the plots I've created with one set of audio data using Octave which is like Matlab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what kinds of "patterns" you are seeking out?  For instance, in your example I see a strong fundamental around 120 Hz along with its nine harmonics, but I haven't any idea whether that is the kind of thing you are looking for.

Comment: @whuber I'm looking for similarities throughout the 90+ audio files that they all have in common.

Comment: Yes, yes: but *what kinds* of similarities?  How do you want to measure similarity?  If you don't give us anything to go on, there's little hope you will get a good answer.  You might get some stock solutions and they might or might not be useful or relevant.

Comment: @whuber I'm thinking frequencies with similar amplitudes and phases would be a good measure.  I'm willing to take suggestions if something would be more worth while

Comment: You have 1 FFT per file or a series of windowed FFT's (i.e. [spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram))? Can you describe qualitatively the *content* you are interested in? (Also, you might check [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).)